# etymology of 「が」 -- Are 「が」 and 「けれども」 (& variants) always interchangeable grammatically?

Tags: grammar, etymology, particle-が

Comparing  「が」 --and--  「けれども」 including variants ( 「だけど」 「けれど」 「けど」 「けども」 ... )

When i was looking at the usage samples below, i noticed that  「が」 and  「けれども」  both fit ALL the usage samples.

1. Are  「が」 and  「けれども」 always interchangeable grammatically ?
2. What's the etymology of 「が」 ? -- It seems odd that two forms not from the same origin can function in such a similar way.  Any explanation for it ?

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/68969/meaning/m0u/

［接助］ 活用語の終止形に付く。

(1. but, however, -- CONTRAST)

> １ 確定の逆接条件を表し、内容の矛盾する事柄を対比的に結びつける意を表す。「言うことはりっぱだ―、することはなってない」「年はとっている―、実に活動的だ」

(2. 前置き)

> ２ ある事実を前置きとして述べ、本題に結びつける意を表す。「経験から言うんだ―、時間には厳しいほうがいい」「これおもしろい本だ―、君読まないか」

(3. sloppy connection)

> ３ 二つの事柄を単に結びつける意を表す。「野球番組も好きだ―、音楽番組も好きだ」「時間もない―、金もない」

［終助］活用語の終止形に付く。

> １ 言い切りを避け、婉曲に表現する気持ちを表す。「あすなら行けるんです―」「父は今日出かけているんです―」
>
> ２ 不安に思ったり、なかばあきらめたりしながらも、事柄の実現などを願う気持ちを表す。「このままお天気が続くといいんです―」

( The above two seem so similar -- are they the same ? )

Comment: They are basically the same. It also means there are still some differences between them.

Comment: が is 大和の言葉 that was used from beginning of times. Asking that is the same thing as asking for the ethymology of the word "and" in English.

Comment: @ValentinDudouyt There's a fairly well established explanation for how が came to be used conjunctively, I believe.

Comment: "and" has an etymology, too. It is cognate to things like "anti-" and "end". By Old English the conjunction "and" had emerged (it was apparently a proto-Germanic innovation), but "and" was also still in use as a preposition meaning against, before, etc. "and heora ordfruman" = "before their creator", "andswaru" = "answer" (lit. against-speaking).

Answer (score 1):

I think 「が」and 「けれども」are always interchangeable grammatically. However, 「だけど」you categorized as one variant is different since it starts with「だ」.

Answer (score 0):

```
   The etymology of English "and" seems interesting too.
```

「が」 格助詞 --（万葉集） 「君が行く」 「君が袖振る」 「近江の海夕波千鳥汝が鳴けば心もしのに古思ほゆ」. . .

I just learned that 
「が」changed from 格助詞 to 接続助詞 and there's a famous example at the very beginning of Genji.

> http://blogs.yahoo.co.jp/miya09132001/26484139.html
>
> 【原文】
>   いづれの御時にか、女御・更衣あまたさぶらひたまひける中に、いとやむごとなききはにはあらぬが、すぐれて時めきたまふありけり。
>
> 【谷崎潤一郎訳】
>   何と言う帝の御代のことでしたか、女御や更衣が大勢伺候していました中に、たいして重い身分ではなくて、誰よりも時めいている方がありました。
>
> 【与謝野晶子訳】
>   どの天皇様の御代であったか、女御とか更衣とかいわれる後宮がおおぜいいた中に、最上の貴族出身ではないが深い御寵愛を得ている人があった。

Scholars can't agree about this が、and Tanizaki's translation is closer to the traditional analysis (as 格助詞).

Please let me know if you know of early usage samples as  接続助詞 -- Thank you.